# Ubuntu 16.04 with Cinnamon and Nvidia Quadro M1200

Tags: 16.04, cinnamon

I am having a hard time getting Cinnamon to work on my new Dell Precision 7520. I installed nvidia-384 package (the latest available). Cinnamon starts fine but eventually it crashes and I get the `cinnamon-session-cinnamon failed` error...any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out.  I've spent the last year trying to install either Ubuntu Cinnamon or Linux Mint with Cinnamon.  I've tried and returned close to a dozen laptops.  The only laptop that worked was a System76 with a GTX1060.  But I didn't need a gaming laptop plus it was eating way too much of my battery life.

I've had many Desktop Linux machines with no problems.  But it seems like all laptop refuse to run Cinnamon and OpenGL correctly.

I finally got an answer from nVidia technical support: "On laptops if your laptop is Optimus based (Optimus means it has both Intel and NVIDIA graphics and switches between them automatically),  unfortunately it won't consistently work with the NVIDIA driver as a display device unless there is a way to disable Optimus or a way to disable the onboard Intel graphics card, usually in system bios."

You can check if it is Optimus based by running lspci -nn.  If you see two VGA devices (one NVIDIA, one Intel) then it is an Optimus system. Luckily, the Dell BIOS allows for me turn off Optimus switching and disable the built in Intel Graphics option.  I was finally able to install Linux Mint with Cinnamon and run my OpenGL programs correctly.